# How to plug 2 devices with 3,5mm jack to laptop with only one 3,5mm audio input

Tags: usb-c, headset, 3.5mm

I use external speakers (CreativeLab T20) with 3,5mm jack and a headset with microphone also with 3,5mm jack on my laptop (HP Elitebook 840 G8), which only has one input for 3,5mm jack. I want to have both plugged at the same time (even if I won't be using them at the same time). E.g. I listen music via speakers, while someone calls me via MS Teams and I need to quickly answer using my headset. I tried using a reduction cable from 3,5mm jack to USB-C and then plugging one of the devices via USB-C port, but it didn't work. Is there a way how to plug both at the same tim, one into 3,5mm jack input and second via USB-C or USB-A input?

Comment: *" but it didn't work"* what about it didn't work? Are both recognised in your sound control panel? If so, then you need something to be able to rapidly switch between them. This used to be good, but I haven't tried it on Win10 - [Audio Switcher](https://audioswit.ch/er)

Comment: Yes, it recognizes both devices however, when headset is plugged into 3,5mm jack and speakers to USB-C via reduction there's no sound from speakers or the sound is breaking. When I switched devices (headset into USB-C via reduction and speakers to 3,5mm input it did not recognize headset's mic. I've checked all sound settings, tried various combinations but nothing worked. I use Win 11.

Comment: So, you need something that can switch between the two, both output and inputs simultaneously [otherwise you'll get your Teams call coming out of your speakers too, which will make it echo for other people in the call.] Also, what exactly is this USB device?

Comment: You mean the reduction I mentioned? I have got this one: https://www.datart.cz/kabel-gogen-usb-c-m-3-5mm-jack-f-0-2m-usbcjackmf01-bily.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwge2iBhBBEiwAfXDBR1Zjeekyh4GFMgDFNcLluPDE3FGM76izuozIjFYycw824vI1Xm223RoCf8MQAvD_BwE

Comment: That's likely the wrong adaptor. They really avoid telling you the full spec, but significantly they use the word 'headphones' not 'headset' which gives the clue that it's only a TRS for stereo out & not a TRRS which can also handle a mic input.

Comment: Hi, I've found an easy and cheap solution - I have bought an external sound card USB-A / 3,5mm jack . It's this product: https://ventiontech.com/collections/usb-external-sound-card/products/usb-external-sound-card-black-metal-typeomtp-ctia. I paid just $8 for it. And it works!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Headphone Splitter.

As for usb-c adapter, this should also work. Important thing to notice, is that it has to be an active adapter (with built in DAC). Some phone adapters are passive and rely on built in phone DAC.

Edit: the thing I use is external audio card that plugs into USB and both devices connect to, but this is probably the most expensive option even if you get one used.

Comment: "A headphone splitter" - care to point to one that would work? OP apparently already has a USB DAC, we just don't know any details yet.

Comment: By headphone splitter I mean a physical device that turns 1 jack output into 2. I found one by searching for "Aux Extension Cable Male to Female Dual Headphone Jack Adapter"

Comment: Problems - impedance mis-match, shorting of the TRRS by using one side with a TRS. This stuff is never as simple as 'buy a splitter' because you're not splitting like for like. Plus, advertising in this sector is notoriously vague [see OP's link above]. Even if this elusive 'magic splitter' existed you'd still have the issue that both would be active at once. Not what you need on a Teams call.